# How to add files to the root of an Eclipse RCP app?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I would like to know if is possible(and how) to add files to the root of an Eclipse RCP app.

I have an AppManual.pdf and i would like to distribute in the root of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_rootfiles.htm

Comment: seems that the answer is there, but cant get it to work, sorry :S

Comment: I struggled with it too ... here's what I did to get a some items added to the root of my app: `root.win32.win32.x86=absolute:file:${builder}/implementerupd.ini

root.win32.win32.x86.folder.jre=absolute:${java.home}`.  This got the file implementerupd.ini and the JRE I built the application with included in the root of the built application.

Comment: my project configuration is based on plugins, as in the link above, i need to do something more, can't get it to work, gonna try something more and report back...

Comment: My project is based on features & plug-in's.