# How to add files to the Eclipse RCP application root directory (application type plugins)?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I saw on official documentation, and some posts that's possible to add files to the root of an Eclipse RCP application : 
http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_rootfiles.htm
and
[How to add files to the root of an Eclipse RCP app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366399/how-to-add-files-to-the-root-of-an-eclipse-rcp-app)

unfortunately, i can't make it works! I would like to distribute a file "launcher.bat" which has to be in the root of the application.
Some information :
- I use eclipse RCP 4 (with eclipse version = kepler).
- My project configuration is based on plugins

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Clément

Answer (score 3):

You must use a **feature** based build for this.

The 'build.properties' file for the **feature** contains the root file directives. For Example

```
bin.includes = feature.xml
root=file:launcher.bat
```

The 'launcher.bat' file to be included would be in root folder of the feature.

Comment: I saw on link posted below that it can be done in a plugins based build. The eclipse application i used is a plugin based application.

Comment: Which link? Both the links in your question require features. To the best of my knowledge you have to use a feature based RCP. It is not difficult to convert a plugin based RCP to features.

Comment: in the first link, in comment, you can read : "my project configuration is based on plugins". In the second link, you can read "When a .product file is based on plug-ins instead of features..."

Comment: Any way of making a file conditional for a specific platform? E.g. the .bat file in the example above goes to Windows, but not Linux.

Comment: @Peteter You can use things like `root.win32.win32.x86=....` See the [Eclipse help](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm)