# Adding Files to the Root of a Eclipse e4 rcp application

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

In order to add some configuration files to an Eclipse e4 rcp application, I have followed the steps from greg-449 in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835247/how-to-add-files-to-the-eclipse-rcp-application-root-directory-application-type):

The application is featured based, and in the feature project folder I have attached the file "test_config_file.txt"

At feature´s 'build.properties' file are the next lines:

```
bin.includes = feature.xml
root=file:test_config_file.txt
```

Basically it is what is stated at the above link.

When I run the product (via Run Configuration), the file is not copied to the folder where the Run Configuration locates the product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in the feature is only used when you build / export a product.

When running the code using a Run Configuration you will have to put the files in the correct location manually. Alternatively your code could support a command line argument to specify the location of the file.

Comment: Thanks greg449, what would be then the optimal solution to implement syntax coloring for an Text Editor where the words to be colored are about 1200 at least.
My intention was to create a file, inside the e4 app installation folder. Then, by means of an OSGI service read the file and returns IRule[] to the SourceViewerConfiguration

Comment: That is a new question - ask a question so everyone can answer.